# How to get actual phrase user said for failed utterance?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

The Alexa Analytics dashboard provide a view of how many utterance are successful and how many are failed as like below.

[image]

But **I can't drill down to see what exact phrase customer** used for my failed utterance.

In addition, Alexa does not provide any feature **to programatically get what exact phrase** used by customer while invoking the skill.

So, as a developer this is a big limitation towards improving skill's ability of recognizing various type of inputs. :-(

**Isn't there any way to get what utterance user used ?**

Answer (score 0):

> I can't drill down to see what exact phrase customer used for my failed utterance

"Failed Utterances" I believe means that the customer invoked an intent and that intent resulted in a failure, not that the utterance couldn't be match to an intent. If you take a look at the "Intents" tab in Analytics you should see a corresponding failure on both the "Failed Utterances Per Intent" and the "Failed Intent" graphs. This could help you find what's causing the failure.

> Isn't there any way to get what utterance user used ?

While you can't, to my knowledge, match the failed intent with a specific phrase (and it may not even be relevant to do so), it might be possible to look at the general phrases spoken by users in [Intent Request History](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/review-intent-history-devconsole.html). I say might because the "skill must have at least 10 unique users per locale in a day, in order for data to be available for that locale for that day". Though even then, this is only the most frequent utterances spoken, but it could never the less be worth taking a look at.